# How to tell if a merge is needed after a pull in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, branch, head

I have a clone of a repository with one head, nice and simple. After pulling in someone else's changes, I have a script that counts the heads to see if a merge is required. But if the other person has made a branch and merged it, "hg heads" shows two heads, and the script thinks it has to merge. What should the test really be?

Before:

```
0 - 1
```

After:

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 3
    \  /
     4 (branch)
```

This doesn't need merging. But a simple comparison of the number of heads before and after would suggest that it does. Why does Mercurial even show more than one head in this case?

Comment: Won't "hg heads default" show only heads on the default branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling `hg heads` call `hg heads --topo` which shows only *topological* heads -- those with no kids.  You're see the head of their merged branch, but since it was merged in it's not a topological head and `--topo` will suppress it.

Comment: Naw, understanding that "head" doesn't mean "has no kids" but means "has no kids in the same named branch" is important, especially if you're using revsets.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have spaces in your branch names, then you can use this script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for b in $(hg branches -q); do
    h=$(hg heads --template "." $b)
    if test ${#h} -gt 1; then
        echo "Branch $b needs merging, it has ${#h} heads"
    fi
done
```

It iterates over each open branch and counts the number of heads on it.

Comment: If stackoverflow allowed two answers to be marked, I'd accept this one too. In my case I can get away with just testing the default branch, so the code wouldn't even be any longer. This works on older versions than --topo as well.

Comment: This set me on the right path, which I now think is to see what `hg heads .` says.  Like the OP, I'm always on the default branch... at the moment, but that might one day change.  The `.` here has a different meaning to the one @Martin passes to the --template switch.

Answer (score 0):

You could clone your repo prior to pulling, and afterwards push into the clone with `--new-branch`. If that complains about new heads, you need to merge.